# Dynamically create react material ui components and then return or render them

Tags: reactjs, dynamic, react-component

I need to create Material ui Tab Components dynamically and render them.

I have the following, given an array of tabNames, which dictate the number of tags to render

```
const tabPanelMarkup = (index, tabMarkup)=>{
    return (
        <TabPanel value={selectedTab} index={index}>
            <section className='no-padding-top margin-bottom-sm margin-top-sm'>
                ...Lotta Divs
                      { tabMarkup }                                        
            </section>
        </TabPanel>
    )
}
```

It's here that I need to build my entire tabs component in a loop

```
const buildTabs = ()=>{
    let markup = '';

    for (let i=0; i < tabNames.length; i++){
        if (i===0)
        {
               /*
                <div className={'page-content'} >
                <MuiThemeProvider theme={kbTheme}>
                    <GenericsTabs
                        value={selectedTab}
                        onChange={handleTabChange}
                    >
                    <GenericsTab
                        label={tabName[i]}
                        className={selectedTab === 0}
                    />
                */
        }
        else{
           /*
           <GenericsTab
               label={tabName[i]}
               className={selectedTab === 0}
           />
           */
        }
    }
   /* </GenericsTabs>  */

   for (let i=0; i < tabNames.length; i++){ 
       {tabPanelMarkup(0, 'Markup A')}
   }

   </MuiThemeProvider>
</div>
   
return   markup;
```

};

How do I do this?
thx

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by putting all the Components/HTML into a long concatenated string and
then

```
a) import parse from 'html-react-parser';
b) return  parse(myString)
```